How to Fix startActivityForResult() is Deprecated In Android In Kotlin
I am Working on a Android App in Kotlin there is payment functionality which is in a main ui thread in a activity but i want to create a separate activity for payment and use coroutines for handling it in other Ui thread,  I am using intent filters to pass data from this activity to my payment activity but this is deprecated  startActivityForResult() How can i Fix this help me please here is little of my code snippet.
fun onClickJoin(view: View) {

        if (binding.joinNowTxt.text.toString() == resources.getString(R.string.join_now)) {
           val paymentIntent = Intent(this,PaymentActivity::class.java).apply {
               putExtra("PAYMENT_AMOUNT",test_list[position].joinAmount.toFloat().toInt())
               putExtra("TEST_ID",test_list[position].testId)
           }
            //this is deprecated
            startActivityForResult(paymentIntent, PAYMENT_REQUEST_CODE)
        } else {
            bindingPayment.choosePaymentLayout.visibility = View.GONE
            if (isAttemp == 2) {
                val intent = Intent(applicationContext, AttemptTestActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("Test_Id", test_list[position].testId)
                intent.putExtra("Category_Id", category_id)
                intent.putExtra("Result_Auto_Publish", result_auto_publish)
                Log.e("Intent Data", "Starting AttemptTestActivity")
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        }

I want Help for this Problem

It was superseded by activity result contract api: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

Here’s how you can update your code

Declare ActivityResultLauncher:
private lateinit var paymentResultLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>


Register the launcher in onCreate():
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Register the launcher
        paymentResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
            if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // Handle the result from PaymentActivity
                val data: Intent? = result.data
                val paymentStatus = data?.getStringExtra("PAYMENT_STATUS")
                Log.d("Payment", "Payment status: $paymentStatus")
            } else {
                // Handle cancellation or failure
                Log.d("Payment", "Payment failed or cancelled")
            }
        }
    }


Launch PaymentActivity using the registered launcher:
fun onClickJoin(view: View) {
 if (binding.joinNowTxt.text.toString() == resources.getString(R.string.join_now)) {
     val paymentIntent = Intent(this, PaymentActivity::class.java).apply {
         putExtra("PAYMENT_AMOUNT", test_list[position].joinAmount.toFloat().toInt())
         putExtra("TEST_ID", test_list[position].testId)
     }
     // Use the registered launcher instead of startActivityForResult()
     paymentResultLauncher.launch(paymentIntent)
 } else {
     bindingPayment.choosePaymentLayout.visibility = View.GONE
     if (isAttemp == 2) {
         val intent = Intent(applicationContext, AttemptTestActivity::class.java)
         intent.putExtra("Test_Id", test_list[position].testId)
         intent.putExtra("Category_Id", category_id)
         intent.putExtra("Result_Auto_Publish", result_auto_publish)
         Log.e("Intent Data", "Starting AttemptTestActivity")
         startActivity(intent)
     }
 }

}



startActivityForResult() was deprecated in Android 11 (API Level 30), you should now use the ActivityResultLauncher with the new Activity Result APIs.
MainActivity
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    // Define the ActivityResultLauncher
    private val resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val data: Intent? = result.data
           
            data?.let {
                val returnValue = it.getStringExtra("key")
                // get here returned value
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

     

        val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
        resultLauncher.launch(intent) // Start the activity for result
    }
}

Second Activity
class SecondActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)

    val resultIntent = Intent()
    resultIntent.putExtra("key", "pass data")

    setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent)
    finish() 
}

}
